# UDP broadcast packets not received in sleep mode

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

My Android application periodically sends and receives UDP broadcast messages on the WiFi LAN.  When the display is on, everything works fine and all messages are sent and received correctly.  When the display goes to sleep the application however stops receiving UDP broadcast messages (but still sends them).

Acquiring the WiFiLock (as well as a Multicast Lock) does not seem to make any difference and my wifi sleep policy is set to WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER.

This is an issue on Android 2.3.3 and 2.3.5 (Samsung galaxy SII phones) but not an issue on an old HTC Hero running cyanogen mod with android 2.3.7.

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

Comment: where are you setting your UDPSocket? Inside an Activity or a Service?

Comment: Inside a Service.  We have also tested it within an Activity and there is no difference.

Comment: and you get a "-1" bytes read from the `InputStream`, signaling the stream has ended?

Comment: No, the `receive` function on the `DatagramChannel` does not return (it is blocked).  The packets simply stop arriving as soon as the device goes to sleep.

Comment: How do you make UDP works on Samsung Galaxy? I have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358552/upd-packets-doesnt-arrive-on-a-samsung-galaxy-tab-7-7-but-they-arrive-on-a-htc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Google Groups thread deals with the problem:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/OpbSdp9FTmA

It has to do with certain chipsets and deep sleep.  Basically, drivers detect when the device goes into a deep sleep and shut down UDP Broadcast Reception.  In my experience, UDP send still works and a UDP send/listen on the device will also hear packets, but it's a ghost, the device is actually deaf.

The following recommendation is what I use:

> 1. Acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, and trap when the screen goes off.  Then disable and reenable the wifi.  This works because the filter 
>      only turns on when the screen goes off, so starting wifi with the 
>      screen off will keep it working until the screen goes off again.  This
>      is what we did before we figured out solution (1).

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
WifiManager wifi;
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
MulticastLock wifilock = wifi.createMulticastLock("just some tag text");
wifilock.acquire();
```

manifest:

```
permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"
```