# how to do Un-targeted packet broadcating on Wifi Direct?

Tags: java, android, wifi, wifi-direct, packets

Is there anyway by which an app can be built using Wifi Direct, By which an un-targeted message packet can be sent over the network, So that anybody can pick it up and process. I mean a packet needs to be sent without any target so that everybody in range can read it and act accordingly. And the system should be such that anyone can enter and leave freely.

PS: I strictly want to use Wifi, But I am Flexible with language and Libraries.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308729/send-broadcast-udp-but-not-receive-it-on-other-android-devices) discusses sending UDP broadcast packets in an ad-hoc WiFi network.

Comment: @adelphus, I guess Android doesn't provide native support for Ad-Hoc's.

Comment: if the message is short enough, you could use the normal service discovery for this.

Comment: @ Dr.Jukka, I can't use Service Discovery, Since it takes long time to do so.