# No UDP broadcast packets after sleep mode on android (not in sleep mode)

Tags: android, udp, wifi, sleep, broadcast

We are in a big problem with  receiving UDP broadcast packets. I'm going crazy...

The problem is:

1-All works well.

2-We can receive packets.

3-If i don't close the android ( home button or key off not pressed), I let android go to sleep (screen off--> OnPause and OnStop)

4-I turn off my Access Point (no wifi, to simulate go out of home).

5-I wait 2 minutes

6-I turn on Access point

7-When Android wakes up, I receive timeouts all the time, in this scenario:

If I launch another time the app with eclipse-> Timeout

If I destroy the app (back button) and restart (onCreate) the app --> timeout

If I press home button to wake up --> timeout

If I disable and enable wifi --> OK, I receive the packets

If I press key off to wake up --> OK, I receive the packets

```
                Asycntask do in background{
                .....
                byte[] message = new byte[1500];
                s = new DatagramSocket(null);
                s.setReuseAddress(true);
                s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(dataclass.getDataclass().GGGPort));
                p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
                s.setSoTimeout(500);
                s.setBroadcast(true);
                dataclass.getDataclass().setGoOut(true);
                s.receive(p);
                }
```

The Questions:

1-What is the difference between home button and key off button to wake up android? They do the same -> OnPause, OnStop--> (unlock) OnRestart. What happens with wifi?

2-Why when the program is running but not receiving,it works ok if I disable/enable wifi? It means that the code is OK... It's a android issue?

P.D: I kill Asynctask OnStop and I execute on Restart

Answer (score 0):

I think that the matter can be that WiFi is turned off on Android to save battery. I do not know exactly conditions to resume WIFi back, probably if you *send* packets, it will be enabled.

To keep on WiFi and receive packets you may need to use [WifiManager.WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html). There's also [MulticastLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html), but seems you do not need it.

From docs:

> Allows an application to keep the Wi-Fi radio awake. Normally the Wi-Fi radio may turn off when the user has not used the device in a while. Acquiring a WifiLock will keep the radio on until the lock is released.
>
> Before using a WifiLock, consider carefully if your application requires Wi-Fi access, or could function over a mobile network, if available. A program that needs to download large files should hold a WifiLock to ensure that the download will complete, but a program whose network usage is occasional or low-bandwidth should not hold a WifiLock to avoid adversely affecting battery life.
>
> Any application using a WifiLock must request the android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission in an  element of the application's manifest.

Comment: Also you may want to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363389/udp-broadcast-packets-not-received-in-sleep-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This thread deals with the problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/OpbSdp9FTmA

Bascially, the solution is

> Acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, and trap when the screen goes off. 
>   Then disable and reenable the wifi.  This works because the filter 
>   only turns on when the screen goes off, so starting wifi with the 
>   screen off will keep it working until the screen goes off again.